# How to avoid duplicate code in Java when you require the same class in two separated applications?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, code-duplication

For the sake of simplicity, let's say that I have a class named "**Dog**".

Then I have two separated applications containing implementations of that class.

1. Application "**A**" does something with the Dog class.
2. Application "**B**" does another something with the Dog class.

Both applications require the **Dog** class, hence it would be duplicated.

---

Now let's say for a moment that:

1. Those applications **can't** be merged into one.
2. The implementations from "**A**" and "**B**" **can't** be moved into another application.

I'm using Spring Boot, if that info helps somehow.

##### Is there a way to fix the duplication of the Dog class?

Comment: You could create a common project to share dog class and import it into both projects

Comment: Or an interface

Comment: In other words, create a library which is shared with both applications.

Comment: jar it and share it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Slaw says you can create a jar/library then use any build tool like maven or gradle and package the jar/library in your archive file when it is built
and here is a link for more info
https://christianlydemann.com/a-guide-to-sharing-code-between-projects/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above solution you can use sonarqube tool to identify code duplication . It will tell you which code is duplicate and how you can fix it
https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.2/MetricDefinitions.html